# If i call a function of my main class in java, from other object which has its own thread, will this function run in separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

Let's say I create Producer from my main. Then, this producer creates it's own thread, and when it produces something calls a function `main.addProduct()`. Will this function execute in the same thread as the producer that called it? Or will it work in the same thread as main, meaning it will wait till all the other tasks are finished before solving it?

To illustrate

```
public class MainP{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Producer p1 = new producer;
        Producer p2 = new producer;
        Producer p3 = new producer;
        p1.start();
        p2.start();
        p3.start();
        System.out.println("I'm ugly");
  }

  public static void prettyFunction(){
        System.out.println("I'm pretty!");
  }

}

public class Producer  extends Thread{
  public void run(){
        while(true)
              MainP.prettyFunction();
}
```

And the question is whether the result will be

```
  I'm ugly
  I'm pretty!
  I'm pretty!
  I'm pretty!
  ...
```

or

```
  I'm pretty!
  I'm pretty!
  I'm pretty!
  I'm ugly
  I'm pretty!
  I'm pretty!
  I'm pretty!
  ...
```

Comment: can you post some sample code , so that it is easy to say which code runs under which thread.

Comment: It's unclear what you asking.

Comment: @srsyogesh I posted some sample code

Comment: As there is no synchronisation here , you cant guess the output . Each and every time you run this you might see different results. Obviously prettyFunction will not run under the main thread instead it runs under the new threads which calls this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads don't care in which objects they are running. Unless they are joined with another thread (i.e. they are stopped) or if they run into code that generates a new thread, everything stays in the thread.

Obviously if you call a method from multiple threads, especially methods that has side effects such as `main.addProduct()`, you need to think about synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

If `main.addProduct()` is being called from your producer thread, then it's that thread where the method is being executed, not your main thread.  It will not wait until other tasks in your main thread are complete, so there is a potential for synchronization bugs here.